# Azure ServiceBus topic has 4 subscriptions without filters. One Subscription not receiving any messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I got an Azure Service Bus with a topic, say "insured".
Under "insured" , there are 4 subscriptions , say , S1,S2,S3 & S4. All the subs are configured with default settings and NO Filters added.

However, when I post a message into the topic, I can see the message is successfully read into S1,S2 and S4.
S3 is never getting that message.

Any one experienced this kind of issue ? Please provide your inputs. Thanks !

a.) Deleted and recreated the Subscription, but of no use.
b.) Deleted and recreated the topic with same subscription names. It worked for a while, again S3 became   vegetative.

Comment: Are you sure about no rules? W/o rules no subscription can receive any messages.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Service Bus topic has 4 subscriptions without filters. One Subscription not receiving any messages:

*There can be more reasons for this occurrence. Check below to resolve it.*

- Verify that the subscription (S3) status is active and the forward message option is enabled.  It will be disabled while creating the subscription.

[image]

- Verify if there are any network or firewall settings configures with the S3 subscription that blocks sending and receiving messages.
- Check if there are any active filters configured in subscription (S3). Because some active filters can prevent messages from being sent and block the activity.

Goto `Service bus namespace -> Topic -> Subscriptions -> S3 -> Filters`

[image]

- Check if anyone else is trying to access the same subscription. If that is the case, the messages may also be consumed before the subscription can read them.

*As mentioned in this [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-tutorial-topics-subscriptions-cli.md), I created four service bus subscriptions, a new topic with a new service bus namespace in my environment and was able to send the messages without any conflicts.*

*Created a topic using AzCLI:*

```bash
az servicebus topic create --resource-group <ResourceGroup> --namespace-name <servicebusnamespace> --name MyTopic
```

[image]

*Created subscriptions as shown:*

```bash
az servicebus topic subscription create --resource-group <Resourcegroup> --namespace-name <namespacename> --topic-name MyTopic --name S1
az servicebus topic subscription create --resource-group <Resourcegroup> --namespace-name <namespacename> --topic-name MyTopic --name S2
az servicebus topic subscription create --resource-group <Resourcegroup> --namespace-name <namespacename> --topic-name MyTopic --name S3
az servicebus topic subscription create --resource-group <Resourcegroup> --namespace-name <namespacename> --topic-name MyTopic --name S4
```

[image]

[image]

***Message received by all the subscriptions successfully:***

[image]